# Difference between Visual C# (Visual Studio) and Mono C# GUI

Tags: c#, linux, visual-studio, window, monodevelop

Can I use a GUI program for sending and receiving serial data that was written on Windows (Visual Studio) on Linux platform using mono framework?

I have found that mono uses different IDEs for GUI development.

Do they have the same components (I don't know what it is called in .NET, I am Java man) as in Visual Studio and is it the same way of development (for example when I double click on a component in Visual Studio, it goes to the coding page with an already written appropriate method name or whatever).

Basically, I want to reuse my GUI base serial program on Linux with Mono.

Answer (score 4):

Mono is a [cross platform runtime implementation for .NET](http://www.mono-project.com/About). This project is developed by Novell and is protected by a patent sharing agreement between MS and Novell.

Since .NET isn't native code (uses MS IL) as long as the features themselves are supported by Mono (and [certain basic adjustments are made in code](http://www.mono-project.com/Guidelines%3aApplication_Portability)) the code will be portable. This will allow you to use .NET assemblies on Linux via Mono and on Windows via the .NET CLR.

The code used to draw the Window itself will vary (as Mono isn't the .NET CLR), but the C# code uses to generate that Window and interact with it will not vary between the implementations (generally speaking).

**NOTE:** You'll have to be sure you're using .NET classes and features that are supported on Mono and the inverse if you're hoping to use Mono related code on MS .NET Runtime.
See: [Mono Technologies](http://www.mono-project.com/Plans)